# Interpret iperf TCP bidirectional measurment

Tags: networking, benchmarking, iperf

I have measured my wlan connection on embedded system with iperf. 
 
I get speed difference in both directions. 
I do not know how can I interpret it, and if it is something to fix.

Test setup:

1. Embedded Platform with USB wlan stick (192.168.1.3):

   - connected to Access point via WLAN
   - running iperf -s (server)
2. Linux PC (192.168.1.2):

   - connected to Access Point via ETH (cable)
   - running iperf -c .... -d (client)
3. Access Point

   - used only for this measurement. No other traffic

According to ​https://serverfault.com/questions/566737/iperf-csv-output-format
I interpret the result as follows : 
 
[4] client-server 8.13 Mbits/sec 
 
[5] server-client 39.8 Mbits/sec

Why do I get this 5 times speed difference ?

```
Tue Jan 27 09:11:58 CET 2015
------------------------------------------------------------
Server listening on TCP port 5001
TCP window size: 85.3 KByte (default)
------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------
Client connecting to 192.168.1.3, TCP port 5001
TCP window size: 16.0 KByte (default)
------------------------------------------------------------
[  4] local 192.168.1.2 port 36557 connected with 192.168.1.3 port 5001
[  5] local 192.168.1.2 port 5001 connected with 192.168.1.3 port 33851
[  4]  0.0-10.1 sec  9.80 MBytes  8.13 Mbits/sec
[  5]  0.0-10.3 sec  48.9 MBytes  39.8 Mbits/sec
```